# AWS - how to store small .yml file as SSM Parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-ssm

could someone advise me **what is the best way to store content of the .yml file in AWS Parameter store?** So it can be retrieved and restored as an .yml file with a proper indentation.

For now, it seems that I may have to convert this .yml into json and then use another utility to convert json into string and only then I can save it. Is this the only way or exists also some more direct approach? Thank you

Comment: Some languages will have a library that can stringify a YAML document. Be aware of the max length of SSM parameters when storing. Or store the YAML document in S3, and store a reference to it in SSM.

Answer (score 3):

On the Linux command line in bash with AWS CLI 2.0.30 you can do:

(any sample .yml file from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML)

```
$ aws ssm put-parameter --type String --name quickie-param --value "`cat sample.yml`"
```

stores the parameter.  To get it:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameter --name quickie-param --query Parameter.Value --output text
```

This will output the .yml file the same way it went in.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: With this method, when I look at the parameter store, how come it's not formatted like a YAML file?

Comment: @ChrisF - I'm not sure on that.  My guess is that the new lines are not converted to HTML `<br />` sequences on the UI.  It does come out correctly from the CLI.

Comment: @ChrisF - I just verified that if I pull up the UI and use the browser tools to copy the existing data into a text file it includes the new lines.  But, since HTML ignores the new lines in this context they are not displayed properly.  You'd need a different UI to properly display the file.

Comment: @stdnbar thanks. the `get-parameter` commands puts it in YAML format so that's all I need.